# how to disable "changes you made may not be saved" popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i'm using

```
window.opener.location.href ='http://localhost/test/index.php';
window.close();
```

to redirect a page and it shows "changes you made may not be saved" popup why?? and how to close that popup `top.window.onbeforeunload = null;` is not working for me

Comment: That popup is not standard behaviour. There must be some code in your page causing it to be displayed. Check for a `beforeunload` event handler. Also note that your question is likely to be downvoted because it's unanswerable in its current form

Comment: we need to see the code before changing the href please

Comment: See [force tab to close without warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76681865/can-tampermonkey-force-tab-to-close-despite-changes-that-you-made-may-not-be-sa/76681866#76681866)