# Can Tampermonkey force tab to close despite "Changes that you made may not be saved"

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

Under certain conditions my userscript allows users to close the page via button press, but when I issue `window.close()` I get the message: "Leave Site? Changes that you made might not be saved".

**I wish to suppress this message and simply close the page.**

I tried adding `beforeunload` and `unload` event handlers, as follows:

```
document.querySelector('#mybutt').addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.close();
});
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
    console.log('This will suppress the Leave/Cancel prompt');
});
window.addEventListener('unload', (event) => {
    console.log('This will suppress the Leave/Cancel prompt');
});
```

and, sure enough, the Leave/Cancel prompt did not appear - but in the console I now have the error `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.`

Is there a work-around?

Comment: Use [`// @grant window.close`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:window.close)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Looks odd, but it works.

Suppose you have code that triggers a message to displayed with a button to close the page. In that code, at the point where you would display the message, add:

```
document.querySelector('#myMsgDiv').style.display = 'block';
location.href = "javascript:(" + function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    window.onunload = null;
    console.log('load/unload hit');
} + ")()";
```

For whatever reason, I had to also add the same code into the button-click handler:

```
document.querySelector('#btnCloseWindow').addEventListener('click', () => {
    location.href = "javascript:(" + function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
        window.onunload = null;
        console.log('load/unload hit');
    } + ")()";
    window.close();
});
```

The page will automatically close.

#### References:

https://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2083577